# Loading 2 images from gallery and placing them into separate ImageButtons

Tags: android

I am making an application for a school project and am having some issues. I currently have a imagebutton that when clicked opens up the gallery where the user choses the image, it then gets placed into the imagebutton. Im trying to create another imagebutton when clicked it opens the gallery and places it into the imagebutton. I have created the two buttons, but everytime I click on each of the buttons and chose an image, it places the image ONLY on the left imagebutton. I am trying to make it where you click the first imagebutton, you chose an image and it places it into that button, click the next button and it places it into that button. It is very hard to explain.
Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.triptych;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my MainActivity2

```
package com.example.triptych;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my layout (activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/load_picture" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/load_picture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.triptych"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here are my strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Triptych</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="load_picture">Load Picture</string>

</resources>
```

If you still don't understand what my issue is and why im trying to do. I have 2 imagebuttons, I want it where you click on them, chose an image and it gets placed on the imagebutton. I want it so I click the left imagebutton, chose an image and that BUTTON is now the image I chose. I want to click the right BUTTON and chose an image and that BUTTON is now the image I chose. I click on the first button, chose an image and it goes on that button, which is correct, the ISSUE im getting is when I click on the RIGHT BUTTON and chose an image, IT GOES TO THE OTHER IMAGEBUTTON, NOT THE ONE I CLICKED. I give up if you don't understand what I mean. Thanks, sorry for sounding rude but each one of my questions have been voted bad, so im trying to get it through to you what I need. If you understand how to do this, please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't see in your code the line where you specify second `ImageButton`, In both activities I see same button `R.id.button2`

Comment: Sorry, I changed the first "button2" to "buttonLoadPicture". "buttonLoadPicture" is the first button and "button2" is the second button

Comment: do you want two activities here ? whats the purpose of using two if you have only one layout for both ? please explain

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what's going on... 
You posted 2 `activities`, but I couldn't find the method where you go to `MainActivity2`, so if you still in same Activity, it will call method `loadImagefromGallery` (which you specified in `onClick`) from first activity all the time, so there is a code for changing only one button. Left button in this case.

I hope this guess is helpful.

Anyways, if you want to do it in each `Activity` you should in method `loadImagefromGallery` do `view.getId();` so you will know which button is clicked. And then set it up to that button.

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable Button clicked_button and initialize it every time you click a button, and this will be the button you change the image for.